# Question on trace Sobolev's theorem for domain $\Omega \times (0,T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, trace

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ be an open,bounded subset with a $C^2-$boundary $\Gamma$. Fix $T>0$.

> Can we claim that $W^{1,2}(\Omega \times (0,T)) \hookrightarrow
>  C([0,T];L^2(\Gamma))(*)$

I believe it could be true since $W^{1,2}(\Omega \times (0,T)) \simeq W^{1,2}([0,T];W^{1,2}(\Omega))$ and additionally by the usual trace map theorem we have $W^{1,2}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^2(\Gamma)$. Finally we know that if $f\in W^{1,2}([0,T];W^{1,2}(\Omega))$ then also $f\in C([0,T];W^{1,2}(\Omega))$.

Although I have most of the pieces of the puzzle in my mind, I can't connect them in a proper mathematical way to justify my claim. What is more, if $(*)$ is indeed true, is this embedding compact?

Any help or hint, or even counterexample is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do **not** have $W^{1,2}((0,T)\times \Omega) \cong W^{1,2}([0,T]; W^{1,2}(\Omega))$. The latter space includes existence and regularity of mixed second-order derivatives $\partial_t \partial_x$, whereas the former space only has first order derivatives.

Comment: @gerw of course, you 're right. I confused it with the $L^p-$Bochner case.

Comment: I would expect that the embedding fails (slightly), here are my thoughts: We have $W^{1,2}((0,T)\times\Omega) = L^2([0,T];W^{1,2}(\Omega))\cap W^{1,2}([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$. The interpolation between the latter two spaces gives $H^{1/2}([0,T]; H^{1,2}(\Omega))$. Now, the one-dimensional space $H^{1/2}(0,T)$ just fails to embed into $C([0,T])$ and, similarly, $H^{1/2}(\Omega)$ just fails to have the trace in $L^2(\partial\Omega)$. Of course, this is not a rigorous argument.

Comment: @gerw Is it correct to say that $f\in W^{1,2}((0,T)\times\Omega)$ implies that $f \in W^{1,1}_2((0,T)\times \Omega)$? (the last denotes the parabolic sobolev space) I see your point. But don't they exist any trace theorems for such domains? Do you have any reference? Thanks for your time

Comment: Yes, this is true. A great resource should be the PDE book by Evans. I am, however, not sure if he covers the parabolic Sobolev space. Of course, you get something like $L^2(0,T;L^2(\partial\Omega))$ and maybe even $L^p(0,T;L^2(\partial\Omega))$ for $p < \infty$ but I am skeptical about $p = \infty$.

Comment: @gerw Great! Stating exactly what  $W^{1,2}((0,T)\times\Omega)$ is helped me a lot. I can describe $L^p((0,T)\times \Omega)$ but with the Sobolev case it was a bit unclear. Your comment was quite helpful. In fact on Evans there are no parabolic Sobolev space... Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized that it is quite easy to see that this embedding fails. Let us consider the one-dimensional situation $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $T = 1$.

Then, $L^2(\partial\Omega)$ is essentially $\mathbb R^2$. Your question about regularity translates into: Does $u(\cdot,0), u(\cdot,1) \in C([0,1])$ for $u \in H^1((0,1)^2)$? This is obviously false since a function in $H^1((0,1)^2)$ can have a singularity/discontinuity at the boundary.